# Android remote services: no communication

Tags: android, service, aidl

I am trying to make an Activity run a certain service.

I followed the tutorial [here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-part-9.html) but adapted to my code, and I can't make it work, because when I am invoking the service after starting and binding it to the activity, my Interface (`IMyRemoteCallsLoggingService`) object does not seem to have the connection properly created.

I have been trying to make this work for several days but I can't seem to get rid of a `NullPointException`.

Not sure if I made myself clear, in which case here's the code:

```
public class MtprojectActivity extends Activity {
[...]
private boolean started = false;

private RemoteSmsLoggingServiceConnection SmsLoggingConn = null;
private RemoteCallsLoggingServiceConnection CallsLoggingConn = null;

private IMyRemoteCallsLoggingService callsLoggingService;
private IMyRemoteSmsLoggingService smsLoggingService;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    retrievePreferences();

    Button prefBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prefsBtn);

    prefBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Explicit intent to call the preferences
            Intent preferencesActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    Preferences.class);
            startActivity(preferencesActivity);
        }
    });
}

private void retrievePreferences() {
    // Get the xml/preferences.xml preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    callsCheckbox = prefs.getBoolean("callsLogChk", false);
    smsCheckbox = prefs.getBoolean("smsLogChk", false);
    locationCheckbox = prefs.getBoolean("locationLogChk", false);

    if (callsCheckbox) {
        startCallsService();
        bindCallsService();
        try {
            invokeCallsService();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

    }
    private void startCallsService() {
    if (started) {
        Toast.makeText(MtprojectActivity.this, "Service already started",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("app.mtproject", "app.mtproject.CallsLoggingService");
        startService(i);
        started = true;
        updateCallsServiceStatus();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "startService()");
    }
}
    private void bindCallsService() {
    if (CallsLoggingConn == null) {
        CallsLoggingConn = new RemoteCallsLoggingServiceConnection();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("app.mtproject", "app.mtproject.CallsLoggingService");
        bindService(i, CallsLoggingConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        updateCallsServiceStatus();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "bindService()");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MtprojectActivity.this,
                "Cannot bind - service already bound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
    private void invokeCallsService() throws RemoteException {
    if (CallsLoggingConn == null) {
        Toast.makeText(MtprojectActivity.this,
                "Cannot invoke - service not bound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        callsLoggingService.dumpCallsLog();
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notApplicable);
        t.setText("It worked!");
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "invokeService()");
    }
}
    class RemoteCallsLoggingServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder boundService) {
        callsLoggingService = IMyRemoteCallsLoggingService.Stub
                .asInterface((IBinder) boundService);
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onServiceConnected()");
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        callsLoggingService = null;
        updateCallsServiceStatus();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onServiceDisconnected");
    }
};
```

I get a `NullPointerException` right on `callsLoggingService.dumpCallsLog()` in the `invokeCallsService()` method, and I'm not sure what's the problem!

Here's the code of the service:

```
public class CallsLoggingService extends Service {
String date, duration, type;

private Handler serviceHandler;
private Task myTask = new Task();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onBind()");
    return myRemoteCallsServiceStub;
}

private IMyRemoteCallsLoggingService.Stub myRemoteCallsServiceStub = new IMyRemoteCallsLoggingService.Stub() {
    public void dumpCallsLog() throws RemoteException {
        CallsLoggingService.this.dumpCallsLog();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreate()");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    serviceHandler.removeCallbacks(myTask);
    serviceHandler = null;
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onDestroy()");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    serviceHandler = new Handler();
    serviceHandler.postDelayed(myTask, 10L);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onStart()");
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            myRemoteCallsServiceStub.dumpCallsLog();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        serviceHandler.postDelayed(this, 86400000L);
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Calling the dumpCallsLog");
    }
}

private synchronized void dumpCallsLog() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String columns[] = new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE,
            CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
    Uri mContacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor c = cr.query(mContacts, columns, // Which columns to return
            null, // WHERE clause; which rows to return(all rows)
            null, // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
            CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER // Order-by clause
            // (ascending
            // by name)

            );
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // Get the field values
            date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
            duration = c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
            type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

}

Thanks a lot everybody for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bindService()` is asynchronous. You cannot use `callsLoggingService` until `onServiceConnected()` is called.

Comment: oh and how can I make sure that I can use it after `onServiceConnected()`?

Comment: but I don't understand it: it's not invoked, but the service is still being started? because the line `Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Calling the dumpCallsLog")` is executed

Comment: You should follow sample codes Android provides. I know there are lots of talent guys outside of Android team. But for basic tasks, what you need is coming from the Android SDK. Just import those projects into Eclipse. Then you'll get the key  :-)